# WordPress styling of single blog post

Tags: css, wordpress, blogs

Is it okay to sometimes style blog post differently, using inline styling?
Changing font size, color, margins and so on for some elements in the specific blog post.

In my case, I have started making a long blog post, and I want to change a lot of styles just for that one post because I can make it more beautiful without touching child theme.

Is that a bad practice (from design and SEO perspective) or is it a normal way of doing things?

Comment: wordpress add a unique class to body tag for each post, so you can simply use it to target a post in particular and add your CSS in external file

Comment: I am so happy that I have asked this question. I didn't know about unique body class for each post!
I found it and I am making changes at this moment.

Can you also give me advice? @TemaniAfif

Should I put the styles in custom CSS, create a new CSS file and include it in child-theme, or even make changes in child-css-theme directly with comments like /* blog post 1*/ and then adding the styles?

Comment: i think you should go with custom CSS as this belong to a post and not to the general template so no need to add it to child theme. By the way you can also consider using plugin that allow you to add custom CSS per post, it's even easier ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif 
I will Google it to see which one is recommended.

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Personally I would always go for a new css file. I like to have things in my project code and not somewhere hidden in the Wordpress admin. But of course there can always be exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

In general, inline styling is bad, it will be hard to manage for the long term. Most blogs attempt to maintain some sort of styling across all posts. This is easier to manage if you leverage an external CSS file.

Comment: e.g. inline style red text color works great until you switch to a theme with a red background.

Answer (score -3):

WordPress is great to spin up a free web page fast.  But later on you'll find it very limited.  Still it's better than a web site with monthly payments (IMHO).  For example a menu bar solution is provided without have to code everything from scratch.  Great, but the font default was an ugly Times Roman.   Ultimately I let the theme fonts stay the same in then Menu.  Then down in the body I had to sprinkle My text body. everywhere below in the page.  It was more cut and text paste pasting but easier than creating my own custom theme...

Comment: `But later on you'll find it very limited.` are you joking ??!! don't you know that wordpress is used by 30% of the websites worldwide ??

Comment: WordPress is limited by theme choices.  Full website ownership can provide things like CSS editing.

Comment: `WordPress is limited by theme choice` so you don't know wordpress at all :) ... there is no limit with wordpress you can pick up any theme and edit whataver you want. Theme are only starting point and you have full control on them ! but the limited is the person who don't know wordpress not wordpress ;)

Comment: I just don't see why you have to interject, my response is comprehensive.  There is a coding expense trade-off between canned web sites, and full custom ones.  Large commercial sites are not using word press.

Comment: @TurboWhizKid , I think this is an unfortunate & common misconception, check out http://www.wpbeginner.com/showcase/40-most-notable-big-name-brands-that-are-using-wordpress/

Comment: The websites mentioned may indeed use word press, just not for FREE.